# XCode UIButton confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I'm having some confusion about UIButton on the storyboard.  I create a new button, change the background color, and the color is always darker than what I choose.  In this example, the actual color that is being displayed is #163ca1 (22, 60, 161), even though I clearly picked something lighter:

[image]

Wassup with that?  The thing is, if I set the background color programmatically it displays the correct color.  This issue extends to other view elements as well.

Also, what does Tint color do?  It seems like it has a different function depending on the element in question, but in this case it seems to have no effect.  I figured it was for the highlighted state, but no matter what I change it to the button text maintains a light blue color on click.